# Is Cucumber broken under Ruby 1.9.1 and Rails 2.3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm installing Ruby 1.9 and Rails 2.3 in Ubuntu 9.04. I want to learn about Cucumber. Is Cucumber broken under Ruby 1.9.1 and Rails 2.3.2?

Comment: Is someone didn't tried cucumber under ruby 1.9 and rails 2.3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it ruby 1.9 says that it works just fine.

http://isitruby19.com/cucumber